# Same product id two apple developer account

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I am developing an `iOS` application an I have two developer accounts, one is mine and the second is for my client. In the application I am using `InAppPurchase` and the problem is that I have added a product id to my account and added it(the same ID) in the account of my client; I know that the product id for the `InAppPurchase` should be unique for an an application ID.

Can I add the same product ID in two applications? If I delete it in my account, would it solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already you submitted inAp purchase product id for apple review? Once it is reviewed in one account then u can't use same id in other account. If not yet submitted for review then safely you can delete it from your account and add it in clients account.

Formate of inAP product id:

```
com.companyName.projectName.inApProductId
```

So follow this syntax, you never face same problem again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the application is submitted for review ( with the account of my client) and i don't delete the account from my account yet, can i delete it now ?

Comment: In client id, already submitted inAp product id for review? before app submission? If not then apple will reject app saying inAp product id is not submitted for review. You can delete it from your account...that doesn't matter....If inAp product id in clients account is already reviewed by apple then no problem..otherwise apple will reject app.